# Cannot get property of class(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 tables

Appointment, Doctors and Appointment_to_Doctor

Here is Appointment class

```
  [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Appointment()
    {
        this.Patient_to_appointment = new HashSet<Patient_to_appointment>();
        this.Appointments_to_Doctors = new HashSet<Appointments_to_Doctors>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Start_appointment { get; set; }
    public string End_appointment { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type_of_appointment { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Patient")]
    public Nullable<int> Patient_id { get; set; }
    public string Kasse { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Patient_to_appointment> Patient_to_appointment { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Appointments_to_Doctors> Appointments_to_Doctors { get; set; }
}
```

Here is Doctors class

```
public partial class Doctor
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Doctor()
    {
        this.Appointments_to_Doctors = new HashSet<Appointments_to_Doctors>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string C_O { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Appointments_to_Doctors> Appointments_to_Doctors { get; set; }
}
```

and third class

```
public partial class Appointments_to_Doctors
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Doctor_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Appointment_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Appointment_id")]
    public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Doctor_id")]
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get id of doctor from select on front , pass it to back end and make select.

So on back-end I have this code.

```
 public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var eventList = ctx.Appointments.Where(e=> e.Appointments_to_Doctors.).Select(e => new
            {
                id = e.Id,
                title = e.Title,
                start = e.Start_appointment.ToString(),
                end = e.End_appointment.ToString(),
                allDay = false
            });
            var rows = eventList.ToArray();
            return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

But here `ctx.Appointments.Where(e=> e.Appointments_to_Doctors.)` after dot, I cannot write `Doctor_id`. Why?

I have this

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Doctor_id' and no extension method 'Doctor_id' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) RS_Main C:\Users\nemes\Source\Repos\RIS_Project_New\RS_Main\Controllers\CalendarController.cs   105 Active

Thank's for help so much!

Comment: Why are your model classes partial classes? If you look at your DB in the `Appointments_to_Doctors` table, do you have a column named `Doctor_id`? It's also somewhat odd that a linking table has nullable foreign keys- this seems like a mistake

Comment: it seems your Problem is you have an icollection<Appointments_to_Doctor> and your property exists on an instance.

try: e=> e.Appointments_to_Doctors.Any(atd => atd.Doctor_id == {yourid})

does that work for you?

Comment: Classes was generated via EF from DB, yes, I have this column in DB@peggy

Comment: @peggy I agree about the nullable foreign keys.. but model classes could be partial classes due to using metadata classes, for data attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*But here ctx.Appointments.Where(e=> e.Appointments_to_Doctors.) after dot, I cannot write Doctor_id. Why?*

This is because in your `Appointments` class you have declared the property `Appointments_to_Doctors` as a collection, which means you will not be able to access individual property members unless if you want to perform some type of method like `.Where`, or `.Any`.. etc on those properties.

You need to change that to:

```
ctx.Appointments_to_Doctors.Where(e=> e.Doctor_Id.Value == yourValue).Select(e => new
    {
        id = /* your value */,
        title = /* your value */,
        start = /* your value */,
        end = /* your value */,
        allDay = false
    });
```

See, this line performs the `.Where` method on the `Doctor_Id.Value`.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar code that works for me in the application that I am working on, try to add this public int Doctor_id in the appointments for doctors table, same for appointments in the same table.

Basically, I believe that you need to store the Id for appointments and doctors

Comment: you are importing the doctor's class, but not linked, so you need the id, same is going to happen for appointments.

Comment: also, I don't know what you are trying to reach, but check first the doctor's appointments and then the doctors, instead of the other way around